# How to aggregate a character and a numeric value without receiving invalid character error

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, tidyr, dplyr

I would like to plot the following data:

```
structure(list(`Sunday NightShifts` = c(2, 3, 3, 3, 3), 
               time = c("t0400_0415_d1", "t0415_0430_d1", "t0430_0445_d1", "t0445_0500_d1", "t0500_0515_d1"),
               day = c("Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday"), 
              `Monday NightShifts` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), 
              `Tuesday NightShifts` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), 
              `Wednesday NightShifts` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), 
              `Thursday NightShifts` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), 
              `Friday NightShifts` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), 
              row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

using tidyverse plot my code is the following:

```
df <- as_data_frame(NightShifts) %>% 
  mutate(timeofday = rownames(NightShifts)) %>% 
mutate(timeofday = as.POSIXct(paste0("2000-01-01 ", timeofday, ":00")))


df_long <- df %>% 
            gather("activity", "value", -timeofday) %>% 
            group_by(timeofday) %>% 
       mutate(rel_value = value / sum(value))
```

However after the above line `(mutate(rel_value = value / sum(value)))` I receive the following error:

`Error in sum(value) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument`

Is this because of `NA`'s?

```
# plot the values as an area-plot
ggplot(df_long, aes(x = timeofday, y = rel_value, fill = activity)) + geom_area(aes(fill=activity)) + labs(x="Time", y="Probabilities", colour="NightShifts", fill="NightShifts") + 

  theme(legend.position="right", axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

I run a traceback ():

```
11: eval(cols[[col]], .data, parent.frame())
10: eval(cols[[col]], .data, parent.frame())
9: mutate(., rel_value = value/sum(value))
8: function_list[[k]](value)
7: withVisible(function_list[[k]](value))
6: freduce(value, `_function_list`)
5: `_fseq`(`_lhs`)
4: eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
3: eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
2: withVisible(eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env))
1: df %>% gather("activity", "value", -timeofday) %>% group_by(timeofday) %>% 
       mutate(rel_value = value/sum(value))
```

Could you help me how to solve this error?

Also I have a basic question how to change this code

```
as.POSIXct(paste0("2000-01-01 ", timeofday, ":00")))
```

to show time in hours and minutes (without date) starting from 04:00 and ending with 03:45.

Many thanks

Comment: No it is not because of `NA`s. What answer do you expect when you do `2 + "t0400_0415_d1"` ?

Comment: @RonakShah thanks so basically I need to convert  t0400_0415_d1 to numeric?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we need the unit difference in minutes, split the 'time' column into two ('time1', 'time2) with `extract` (from `tidyr`), convert to Datetime class (`as.POSIXct`) get the difference between the columns and add with the 'Sunday NightShifts' column

```
library(tidyverse)
NightShifts %>% 
   extract(time, into = c("time1", "time2"), 
         "^t(\\d+)_(\\d+)_.*", remove = FALSE) %>%
   mutate_at(vars(time1, time2), as.POSIXct, format = "%H%M") %>% 
   mutate(Diff = as.numeric(difftime(time2, time1, unit = "min") + 
            `Sunday NightShifts`))
```

Comment: thank you for your help and time -great idea- when I run the code I receive the following error Error in `[.data.frame`(., time, into = c("time1", "time2"), "^t(\\d+)_(\\d+)_.*",  : 
  unused arguments (into = c("time1", "time2"), remove = FALSE)

Comment: @user10974052  I guess you were using `tidyr::extract` in case it is masked by another function of same name (from `magrittr`), specify explictly `NightShifts %>% tidyr::extract(time, into = `